# Brightness calibration via keyboard shortcut

Tags: display, brightness

When I set the brightness to the minimum it stays at zero visibility, which seems to me as a calibration error.

It's very frustrating if you don't have keyboard shortcuts to increase it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you can adjust brightness it probably means you are using a laptop (correct me if I'm wrong). If you are on a laptop you can adjust brightness using the function key combinations (e.g. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>).

On desktop it probably not directly possible - usually depends upon the monitor you're using. Check for on physical buttons for options like auto-calibration etc.

Using GUI:

[image]

or

[image]

Using CLI: Reference: https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-change-screen-brightness-in-ubuntu-using-command-terminal.html

Get the connected monitor:

`xrandr | grep " connected" | cut -f1 -d " "`

Adjust the brightness (for output = `VGA-1`):

`xrandr --output VGA-1 --brightness 0.5`

As for keyboard shortcut you've mentioned you can create custom shortcut using the above command here:

[image]